# select two different color value with in four select box and give same option rest of two select option

Tags: jquery

```
<select name="form_textcolor1">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<select name="form_textcolor2">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<select name="form_textcolor3">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<select name="form_textcolor4">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

i have four select box and i want to choose two diffrent color value with in four select box , after then give same color value option rest of two select box.

i mean to say in first select box choose red and second pink after then give option for 3rd and 4th select box red and pink.

i m not getting how to do it with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this (example for red):

```
$('option').css( 'color', function() {
    var color = '#000000';
    switch ( $(this).attr('value') ) {

        case ('Red'): {
            color = '#ff0000';
            break;
        }

        ...

        default: {
            break;
        }
    }

    return color;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure if I understand your problem statement clearly. Please have a look if the solution below is what you are looking for.

```
<select id='select-1'  name="form_textcolor-1">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<select id='select-2' name="form_textcolor-2">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<select id='select-3' name="form_textcolor-3">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<select id='select-4' name="form_textcolor-4">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var allOptions = ['select-1', 'select-2','select-3','select-4'],
        selectedOptions = [];
    $("select[id^='select-']").change(function(){
        selectedOptions.push($(this).attr('id'));
        allOptions.splice( $.inArray($(this).attr('id'), allOptions), 1 );

        if(selectedOptions.length == 2){
           for(var i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++){
               $("#" + allOptions[i]).val($("#" + selectedOptions[i]).val());
           }
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WThvQ/1) is the JSFiddle.

Comment: wht about if i choose first and four select box

Comment: you got it my problem i know, but i can choose any selectbox with in four ,

Comment: You can add further options in same line it's done for the first 2.

Comment: @vikastyagi What should be the expected behavior if someone chooses selectbox four?

Comment: if i choose 1 and 4 select box , i need same value for 2 and 3wht i have choosed in 1 and 4

Comment: @vikastyagi I've updated the answer. Does it fulfill your requirement now?

Answer (score 0):

This will work also vice versa: select1 and select3 will change each other. same for 2 and 4. I added some classess in the select.

```
        <select class="select1" name="form_textcolor">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select2" name="form_textcolor">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select3" name="form_textcolor">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select4" name="form_textcolor">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript:

```
            $('select').on('change', function(){
        var value = $('.select1').val(),
            value3 = $('.select3').val();
        if(value) {
            $('.select3').val(value);
        } else if (value3) {
            $('.select1').val(value3);
        }
    
    
        var value2 = $('.select2').val(),
            value4 = $('.select4').val();
        if(value2) {
            $('.select4').val(value2);
        } else if (value4) {
            $('.select2').val(value4);
        }
            })
```

If you dont need that select3 will change select 1 and select 4 changes select2 then just delete both else if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you ....its checked

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>



        <select name="form_textcolor1">
            <option value="">Select Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        </select>
        <select name="form_textcolor2">
            <option value="">Select Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        </select>
        <select name="form_textcolor3">
            <option value="">Select Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        </select>
        <select name="form_textcolor4">
            <option value="">Select Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" onclick="checkColor();" value="submit"></button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkColor () {
            var a = $("[name=form_textcolor1]").val();
            var b = $("[name=form_textcolor2]").val();
            var c = $("[name=form_textcolor3]").val();
            var d = $("[name=form_textcolor4]").val();
            if(a==b|| a==c||a==d || b==c ||b==d|| c==d)
            {
            if (a==b)
            {
                if (a==c || c==d || a==d )
                {
                    alert("combination incorrect");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("combination correct");
                }
            }
            if (a==c)
            {
                if (a==b || b==d || a==d )
                {
                    alert("combination incorrect");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("combination correct");
                }
            }
            if (a==d)
            {
                if (a==b || b==c || a==c )
                {
                    alert("combination incorrect");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("combination correct");
                }
            }
            if (b==c)
            {
                if (a==b || b==d || a==d )
                {
                    alert("combination incorrect");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("combination correct");
                }
            }
            if (b==d)
            {
                if (a==b || b==c || a==c )
                {
                    alert("combination incorrect");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("combination correct");
                }
            }
            if (c==d)
            {
                if (a==b || b==c || a==c )
                {
                    alert("combination incorrect");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("combination correct");
                }
            }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("combination corect");
            }
        }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/whKMY/)</kbd>

```
var select_all = $('select[name^="form_textcolor"]'), //cache selector
    sel_first = select_all.filter(':lt(2)'),//get 1st two select
    sel_last = select_all.filter(':gt(1)');//get last two select
sel_last.prop('disabled', true);//disable last two select
sel_first.change(function () {//attach change function 1st select
    sel_first.find('option').prop('disabled', false); //enable all 1st select options
    sel_first.not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true); //disable option selected by current in the other 1st select
    $(this).find('option[value="' + sel_first.not(this).val() + '"]').prop('disabled', true); //disable option of current select which is selected by other select
    var selected_sel = sel_first.find('option:selected[value!=""]'); //get selected options whose value is not "" from 1st two selects
    if (selected_sel.length == 2) { //if length of selcted options is 2 from two selects
        var selected_options = selected_sel.map(function () { //get the options selected
            var txt = $(this).text();
            return '<option value="' + txt + '">' + txt + '</option>';
        }).get().join('');
        sel_last.html(selected_options).prop('disabled', false).eq(0).prop('selected', true);//assign it two last two select and enable them
    } else {
        sel_last.prop('disabled', true); //disable last two select if length of selected option from 1st two selects is not 2
    }
});
```